# Heap Memory Visualization

Tags: c, visual-studio, heap-memory

I was wondering if there is a way to visualize (inside Visual Studio) how much of the heap memory I'm using during the execution of my program.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Memory Usage Diagnostic Tool in Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2019

> The Memory Usage tool lets you take one or more snapshots of the
>   managed and native memory heap to help understand the memory usage
>   impact of object types. You can collect snapshots of .NET, native, or
>   mixed mode (.NET and native) apps.

Here's a great blog article on its usage as well: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/analyze-cpu-memory-while-debugging/